# How to store a tree of traits in rust?

Tags: rust

I have the next code:

```
use std::{
    fmt::Debug, 
    rc::Rc, 
    cell::RefCell,
};

pub trait ILifeCycle {
    fn on_start(&mut self);
    fn on_update(&mut self);
    fn on_stop(&mut self);
}

pub trait IObject: Debug {
    fn name(&self) -> &String;
    fn is_active(&self) -> bool;

    fn set_name(&mut self, name: String);
    fn set_is_active(&mut self, is_active: bool);
}

pub type INodeRef = Rc<RefCell<Box<dyn INode>>>;

pub trait INode: IObject + ILifeCycle {
    fn add_child(&mut self, node: impl INode);
    fn find_by_name(&self, name: String) -> Option<INodeRef>;
    fn remove_child(&mut self, node: impl INode);
    fn children(&self) -> &Vec<INodeRef>;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Node {
    name: String,
    is_active: bool,
    children: Vec<INodeRef>,
}

impl ILifeCycle for Node {

    fn on_start(&mut self) {
        todo!()
    }

    fn on_update(&mut self) {
        todo!()
    }

    fn on_stop(&mut self) {
        todo!()
    }
}

impl IObject for Node {
    fn name(&self) -> &String {
        &self.name
    }

    fn is_active(&self) -> bool {
        self.is_active
    }

    fn set_name(&mut self, name: String) {
        self.name = name;
    }

    fn set_is_active(&mut self, is_active: bool) {
        self.is_active = is_active;
    }
}

impl INode for Node {
    
    fn add_child(&mut self, node: impl INode) {
        todo!()
    }

    fn find_by_name(&self, name: String) -> Option<INodeRef> {
        todo!()
    }

    fn remove_child(&mut self, node: impl INode) {
        todo!()
    }

    fn children(&self) -> &Vec<INodeRef> {
        &self.children
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct SpriteNode {
    node: Node,
    sprite: Vec<u8>,
}

impl ILifeCycle for SpriteNode {

    fn on_start(&mut self) {
        self.node.on_start();
    }

    fn on_update(&mut self) {
        self.node.on_update();
    }

    fn on_stop(&mut self) {
        self.node.on_stop();
    }
}

impl IObject for SpriteNode {
    fn name(&self) -> &String {
        self.node.name();
    }

    fn is_active(&self) -> bool {
        self.node.is_active();
    }

    fn set_name(&mut self, name: String) {
        self.node.set_name(name);
    }

    fn set_is_active(&mut self, is_active: bool) {
        self.node.set_is_active(is_active);
    }
}

// Other node types
```

The problem is `INodeRef` the compiler can't turn it into the object:

```
the trait `INode` cannot be made into an object
consider moving `add_child` to another trait
consider moving `remove_child` to another trait
only type `world::Node` is seen to implement the trait in this crate, consider using it directly instead
`INode` can be implemented in other crates; if you want to support your users passing their own types here, you can't refer to a specific typerustcClick for full compiler diagnostic
```

How to implement a such tree structure in rust-way? All these `Rc<RefCell<Box<dyn INode>>>` look like a hell already.

Comment: Why not just `Box<dyn INode>`?

Comment: And why do you prefix traits with `I`? This is not conventional in Rust.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I started from `Box<dyn INode>`, it leads to the same error

Comment: Please look at [Object safety](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman just it's convenient for me. There are no strict rules for names as I got.

Comment: Why do you use trait objects for children instead of concrete types? Do you really need to mix node types? Will an enum work better for you?

Comment: No, there aren't strict rules, but there are conventions, and breaking them is very... non-conventional.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman unfortunately, I can't use `enum` in this case cuz new types can still be created in other libs... And yes, I need to support various types. I am a noobie in rust, so I can't get how to make it in rust-way, not typical OOP.

Comment: Your options are either to omit the `add_child()` and `remove_child()` from the trait object by adding a `where Self: Sized` bound to them (if you don't need to access them from `INodeRef`), or taking `Box<dyn INode>` for `add_child()` and `&dyn INode` for `remove_child()`, although it's not clear to me how you intend to do the comparison for removal.

Comment: Also, please post the full error from `cargo check`, not your IDE, as many times it is missing important details.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman thank you for help the second option is that I need. Seems I got my mistake